# erro when get ruby version

Tags: ruby, linux

I just do this command `sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/ruby /user/bin/ruby1-9`. Now when I wont get ruby version (`ruby -v`) ...Error , ruby not installed and you may install it by this command `sudo apt-get install ruby`. But ruby was installed. How revert this command `sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/ruby /user/bin/ruby1-9` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply delete the symbolic link by calling `sudo rm /usr/bin/ruby`. The problem you are facing is because it seems your executable is called ruby1-9. So all you need to do is type `ruby1-9 -v` and use ruby1-9 wherever you need ruby.

Comment: done. but terminal still offers install ruby when I do ruby -v

Comment: is `ruby1-9` a file or directory?

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev I think it is a directory for the modules.

Comment: don't know :), I think it's folder

Comment: you can find this out by typing `ls -d /usr/bin/ruby1-9`

Comment: No such file or directory.

Comment: Probably easier to reinstall Ruby ?

Comment: This command ls -d /usr/bin/ruby1.9 write /usr/bin/ruby1.9

Comment: Oh...THANK YOU MAN )
so, i put this command /usr/bin/ruby1.9 -v
and it write ruby 1.9.0 (2008-10-04 revision 19669) [x86_64-linux]
VICTORY! )))

Comment: @JohnOggy you're welcome :) I will add this to the answer to make it helpful for others.